# reinterpret_cast for 'serializing' data, byte order and alignment on receiving end

Tags: c++, serialization, casting, reinterpret-cast

If we have a POD struct say A, and I do this:

```
char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(A);
char buf[20];
for (int i =0;i<20; ++i)
   buf[i] = ptr[i];
network_send(buf,..);
```

If the recieving end remote box, is not necessarily same hardware or OS, can I safely do this to 'unserialize':

```
void onRecieve(..char* buf,..) {
  A* result = reinterpret_cast<A*>(buf); // given same bytes in same order from the sending end
```

---

Will the 'result' always be valid?  The C++ standard states with POD structures, the result of reinterpret_cast should point to the first member, but does it mean the actual byte order will be correct also, even if the recieving end is a different platform?

Comment: No, it won't always be valid. Consider the case where one platform is big-endian and the other little-endian. [Network byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_in_networking) arose from this very problem...

Comment: padding can also vary between platforms

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot. You can only ever cast "down" to `char*`, never back to an object pointer:

```
  Source                  Destination
     \                         /
      \                       /
       V                     V
 read as char* ---> write as if to char*
```

In code:

```
Foo Source;
Foo Destination;

char buf[sizeof(Foo)];

// Serialize:
char const * ps = reinterpret_cast<char const *>(&Source);
std::copy(ps, ps + sizeof(Foo), buf);

// Deserialize:
char * pd = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Destination);
std::copy(buf, buf + sizeof(Foo), pd);
```

In a nutshell: If you *want* an object, you have to *have* an object. You cannot just pretend a random memory location *is* an object if it really isn't (i.e. if it isn't the address of an actual object of the desired type).

Comment: Alright, I'll take the bait... *Why* can't we just pretend a random memory location is an object (assuming the platform is the same, and that the source bytes are from a valid (POD) object of the same type)? +1 for your method though. It takes care of alignment issues too, should there be any.

Comment: @Cameron, the OP is asking about whether this is safe if the platform is _not_ necessarily the same

Comment: @bdonlan: Well yes, but Kerrek seems to be saying that it's not (or rather, shouldn't be done) even on the same platform.

Comment: @Cameron Theoretically, the standards don't require object representation to remain the same over two runs of the same program, even. However, in practice, as long as you respect the alignment rules, you're usually okay.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. @bdonlan I didn't consider that case. I recall Stroustrop's manuals somewhere said only that it wasn't 'portable' (i.e. across different platforms).  In all my testing using the same couple of platforms at least, it never failed.

Comment: @user1177344: When you profile your program and find that this isn't a bottleneck, then write portable code, because it's one less thing for you to worry about. If you do require the direct cast for genuine reasons, then document that piece of code well, say why it's OK on your platform, and maybe leave a note in the project documentation in the "Portability" section.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a templatefor this and letting the compiler handle it for you

```
template<typename T>
struct base_type {
    union {
        T    scalar;
        char bytes[sizeof(T)];
    };
    void serialize(T val, byte* dest) {
        scalar = val;
        if is_big_endian { /* swap bytes and write */ }
        else { /* just write */ }
    }
};
```